# Is there a limit on the number of layout files you can include on an Android project?

Tags: android, xml, layout, limit, android-resources

I have a really weird bug on my app. At a certain point of the development process, some items from certain layouts started to glitch, disappearing and reappearing in other places. Crawling trough the commits, we found that the glitch started after *adding a single xml file* to the project. At start, we thought it was an error in the code of that layout, because the glitch was gone after deleting the file. To make the story short, we discovered that the glitch appeared after *adding files to the project*, *even* if we added empty xml files, *even* if those files were never used trough the entire app! The strange behavior appeared while testing on a Samsung Galaxy Ace, and the magic number there was 107 xml files (everything worked fine with 106, after adding one more it glitched hard). The real question is... can someone explain why would this happen? is there a real limit on the layout files you can use? or probably it's an issue with the number of references that the R file must hold?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you test on emulator ? Maybe could you see how used is the CPU and/or GPU, it's maybe just a problem with the (quite old) Galaxy Ace.